# usort Date Assistance

Tags: php, date, usort

I am trying, unsuccessfully, to sort my list by one of my template fields ($fields[3]) which is a text input field with a date inside it. The problem is that because of the format of the date it will not sort correctly because I guess it is just comparing numbers.

I think I need to change the dateformat before sorting occurs but have so far failed to do this.

I am trying to use the usort function like so (field 3 is the one with the date in which is formatted like this dd/mm/yyyy),

```
if (!function_exists('do_sort')) {
    function do_sort($a, $b) {
        return $a->fields[3] > $b->fields[3];
    }}

$data = $params['data'];
usort($data, 'do_sort');
$smarty->assign('sorted', $data);
```

This sorts the data but as before, because I haven't changed anything, not in the correct order. Can anyone help me reformat the date prior to sorting?

Many thanks

Chris

Answer (score 4):

Managed to do it. If anyone else is interested I used the following function:

```
   function date_compare($a, $b)
    {
        $t1 = strtotime($a->fields[3]);
        $t2 = strtotime($b->fields[3]);
        return $t1 - $t2;
    }    
    $data = $params['data'];
    usort($data, 'date_compare');
    $smarty->assign('sorted', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the strings to timestamps first:

```
function do_sort($a, $b) {
    $aval = strtotime($a);
    $bval = strtotime($b);
    if ($aval == $bval) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $aval < $bval ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Quick question: how does `strtotime()` determine if the pattern is `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`? I'd imagine that there'd be some dates for which `strtotime()` doesn't work because of that issue.

Comment: Understood formats are listed here: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Comment: If you need something beyond those, you'll probably have to use something that's locale-aware, like Zend_Date. (Or just parse it yourself.)

Comment: I see. Note to OP: change your date formats from `dd/mm/yyyy` to either `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd-mm-yyyy` if you plan on using `strtotime()`.